# Write Live expressions in after effects cc using Extendscript?

Tags: scripting, expression, extendscript, after-effects

I am trying to write a script for after effects CC using Extendscript. I wonder if it is possible to add live expressions to a layers properties like `thisComp.layer("Layer 1").transform.position` and so on.

Hoping it is possible.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
var expString = "thisComp.layer(\"My-Layer\").transform.position";
var prop = app.project.item(index).layer(index).transform.position;
if(prop.canSetExpression === true){
    prop.expression  = expString;
}
```

Replace the `index` with your layers `index` and item `index`. If you use strings in your expression like

```
thisComp.layer(\"My-Layer\").transform.position
```

You need to escape them properly. Don't use single quotation marks in your expressions. e.g. `'My-Layer'`. This creates new problems.

Take a look into the [After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf](https://blogs.adobe.com/aftereffects/files/2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf?file=2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf)